# responsive background-image leaving white space when resized

Tags: css, background-image, whitespace, space

I have created a responsive div that uses background-image, only problem is when I resize the browser window, the image leaves a white space below it.

HTML

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#background-image {
    background-image:url('http://tiny.cc/pm334x');
    height: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

CSS

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background-image"></div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnwe098m/1/

At the moment I'm out of options, I have tried a number of different "solutions" but none have worked. I could go for creating multiple images, for different resolutions using media queries, but I'd rather keep it simple.

Many Thanks

Comment: did you try using background-size: cover?

Comment: I did, for some reason it is not working with the actual image I am using which is 1920 x 320 in resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cover` as `background-size` instead of `contain`

```
background-size: cover;
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#background-image {
    background-image:url('http://tiny.cc/pm334x');
    height: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="background-image"></div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

The snippet above may not actually show the difference, so here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnwe098m/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code below to `#background-image` id

```
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:

```
background-size: cover;
```

rather than:

```
background-size: contain;
```

I have updated the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/qnwe098m/2/

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with the actual image I am using, for some reason it is not resizing like the previous image. http://jsfiddle.net/qnwe098m/4/

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Looks like it is covering the div to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
#background-image {
  background-image:url('http://tiny.cc/pm334x');
  height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnwe098m/1/